# Place a QToolButton on top of a video frame

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, video-streaming, pyqt4

Below is the code for a video monitoring system. I want to add a QToolButton at bottom right corner of each camera.

I have two requirements for this button. First is that the **button should only be visible when I hover the mouse over that video frame**. Second, I want to have **drop up** functionality instead of a drop down.

**Edit**: If possible I would also like to remove the small arrow sign of the QToolButton.

How can I achieve this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils

class CameraWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, stream_link=0, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)

        # Slight offset is needed since PyQt layouts have a built in padding
        # So add offset to counter the padding 
        self.offset = 16
        self.screen_width = width - self.offset
        self.screen_height = height - self.offset
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio

        self.camera_stream_link = stream_link

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None
        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))


            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)

    def get_video_frame(self):
        return self.video_frame


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create main application window
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Camera GUI')

    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)
    mw.showMaximized()

    # Dynamically determine screen width/height
    screen_width = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry().width()
    screen_height = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry().height()

    # Create Camera Widgets 
    username = 'Your camera username!'
    password = 'Your camera password!'

    # Stream links
    camera0 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.43:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera1 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp'.format(username, password)
    camera2 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera3 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.40:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera4 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.44:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera5 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.42:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera6 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.46:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)
    camera7 = 'rtsp://{}:{}@192.168.1.41:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'.format(username, password)

    # Create camera widgets
    print('Creating Camera Widgets...')
    zero = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera0)
    one = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera1)
    two = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera2)
    three = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera3)
    four = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera4)
    five = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera5)
    six = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera6)
    seven = CameraWidget(screen_width//3, screen_height//3, camera7)

    # Add widgets to layout
    print('Adding widgets to layout...')
    ml.addWidget(zero.get_video_frame(),0,0,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(one.get_video_frame(),0,1,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(two.get_video_frame(),0,2,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(three.get_video_frame(),1,0,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(four.get_video_frame(),1,1,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(five.get_video_frame(),1,2,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(six.get_video_frame(),2,0,1,1)
    ml.addWidget(seven.get_video_frame(),2,1,1,1)

    print('Verifying camera credentials...')

    mw.show()
```

Comment: So, your "video frame", is actually a QLabel, right?

Comment: @musicamante, yes that's correct.

Comment: Then, again, please *always* try to keep your examples as minimal as possible. Your question has nothing to do with video capturing, and 95% of your code is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @musicamante actually I didn't want to miss out on any details which may make it difficult for anyone to understand the code and also as you commented on my other question that the example should be in a form where one can copy, paste and run on his machine without any difficulties.

Comment: It actually made your code *more* difficult to understand. You want to show a button over a QLabel, that's it. Yes, the example has to be reproducible, but also **minimal**. If you cannot reduce your current code to make it reproducible, create a new script that only implements the necessary parts: in your case, it would have been enough to set a temporary QPixmap for the label, because that's what your code does.

Comment: @musicamante Okay, will keep that in mind from next time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add a *child* button to the label, by using the label as a parent in the constructor (this can also be done by means of `setParent()`).

```
class VideoWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # create a button that is a *child* of *this* widget ("self")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        # hide the button, otherwise it will be automatically visible as soon
        # as this VideoWidget will be shown
        self.button.setVisible(False)
        self.buttonOffset = 5

        # just for testing
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('frame.png'))

    def updateButtonGeometry(self):
        # create a rectangle based on the sizeHint of the button, it will 
        # be used to set its geometry
        geo = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), self.button.sizeHint())
        # move the rectangle to the bottom right corner, using an offset 
        # as a margin from the border
        offset = QtCore.QPoint(self.buttonOffset, self.buttonOffset)
        geo.moveBottomRight(self.rect().bottomRight() - offset)
        # apply the geometry
        self.button.setGeometry(geo)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.button.setVisible(True)
        self.updateButtonGeometry()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.button.setVisible(False)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateButtonGeometry()


class VideoContainer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    '''
    An example class to display some widgets in a grid layout
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.videoWidgets = []
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                videoWidget = VideoWidget()
                layout.addWidget(videoWidget, row, col)
                self.videoWidgets.append(videoWidget)
```

A consideration about your code (which was unnecessary complex for this matter, by the way): you're creating VideoWidget classes, but you are never using them, making them almost useless. Just subclass from QLabel and use its instances directly.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but can you throw some light on how exactly I have to make label as a parent in the constructor and also where am I making ```VideoWidget``` class.

Comment: The label becomes the parent *exactly as shown in the code*: `self.button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)`. Subclass from QLabel instead of QWidget, replace everything related to `self.label` in your code with `self`, and add those widgets to the layout by using `ml.addWidget(zero,0,0,1,1)`, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: What is that you don't understand?

Comment: I'm unable to integrate your code in mine. There are actually couple of things I don't understand. 1)  You said that I have to replace everything related to ```self.video_frame``` with ```self```, I don't get that. 2) What is the purpose of ```VideoContainer``` class in your code?

Comment: `VideoContainer` is just an example to show the result. I said that you're subclassing from QWidget that you're not *really* using, since you're actually showing the QLabel, so you should directly subclass from QLabel instead, and, obviously, you don't need to create `self.video_frame`, since `self` (the subclass instance) will be the actual label, so all references to `self.video_frame` should be replaced by `self` alone.